# FileHelpers, как связать заголовок CSV файла с полями в классе

Tags: c#, csv

Я использую замечательную библиотеку **FileHelpers 3.2** для чтения CSV файла с заголовком, например:

```
aa;bb;cc
11;22;33
44;55;66
```

Для этого я создаю клас:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
[IgnoreFirst]
public class Record
{
    public int Field1;
    public int Field2;
    public int Field3;
}
```

и затем загружаю данные:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Record>();
var result = engine.ReadFile(fileName);
```

Если вдруг формат CSV файла изменится например так:

```
cc;bb;aa
11;22;33
44;55;66
```

или так:

```
ff;bb;сс
11;22;33
44;55;66
```

то я никогда об этом не узнаю и буду грузить не правильные данные.

Вопрос как сопоставить имя колонки в CSV файле с именем поля в классе `Record`?

Я нашел похожий вопрос на stackoverflow (использовать атрибут `FieldTitle`), но он видимо был удален в новой версии и больше не существует.

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас там замечательным является, но вот [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) как раз является замечательной.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте заголовок перед чтением "вручную", это ведь не сложно:

```
var header = engine.GetFileHeader();
bool valid = File.ReadLines(fileName, engine.Encoding).FirstOrDefault() == header;
Console.WriteLine(valid);
```

При желании можно из этого "состряпать" метод-расширение для `EngineBase`:

```
public static class EngineBaseEx
{
    public static bool CheckHeaders(this EngineBase engineBase, string fileName)
    {
        return File.ReadLines(fileName, engineBase.Encoding).FirstOrDefault()
                    == engineBase.GetFileHeader();
    }
}
```